# TextBox(HtmlHelper, String) - is view model also searched for a value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Pro Asp.Net MVC 4 (pg 535):

> The string argument is used to search the view data, ViewBag and view
>   model to find a corresponding data item that can be used as the basic
>   for the input element. So, for example, if you call
>   `@Html.TextBox("DataValue")`, the MVC Framework tries to find some
>   item of data that corresponds with the key DataValue. The following
>   locations are checked: • ViewBag.DataValue • @Model.DataValue

Book states that an overload of a Html.TextBox which takes a single string argument checks both `ViewData` and *view model* to obtain the value for display. But after experimenting a little, it seems it only checks `ViewData` for a value, but not also a *view model*.

Thus, in the output generated from `Html.TextBox` the `value` attribute is set to an *empty string*:

```
public class Person 
{
    public string FirstName = "Leila";
}
```

*.cshtml:

```
@model HelperMethods.Models.Person
                  ...   
@Html.TextBox("FirstName")
```

Output:

```
                  ...
<input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="" />
```

So is the book wrong and `TextBox(HtmlHelper, String)` checks only `ViewData` or does it also check a *view model*?

**UPDATE:**

```
public class Person 
{
    public string FirstName = "Leila";
}


public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View((object)new Person());
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@model Mvc4.Controllers.Person

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
     <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Index</title>
     </head>
     <body>
        @Html.TextBox("FirstName")
     </body>
    </html>
```

Much appreciated

Comment: yes, it does. it's not strongly typed so errors can happen, but if used right, it should reference your model FirstName property. please post your entire form.

Comment: Yep, just tested and it worked fine for me too.

Comment: @Dave A: I posted the entire form. Please see the update

Comment: @SimonC: I posted the entire form. Please see the update

Comment: The beginform is still missing

Comment: @Dave A :Even if I have @using(Html.BeginForm()){ @Html.TextBox("FirstName") }, it still doesn't check view model for a value

Comment: that's true. I didn't notice the missing get-ter so I was reaching for a cause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just did a quick test and it seems that it has to be a property and not a field.

So this should work:

```
public class Person 
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Nice catch. I missed it completely!